# Event listener inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a `select` on my page:

```
<select id='cat'>
    <option value='a'>A</option>
    <option value='b'>B</option>
    <option value='all'>all</option>
</select>
```

With a javascript function that handles which options have to be displayed:

```
function funcName(aList) {
    // populates the options for the select tag
    $("#cat").on("change", function(){
        // some computation;
    });
    // uses aList to update some div data
 }
```

What I'm trying to do is if the selected option is `all`, I have to display everything in `aList`, otherwise based on the selected option I have to display only the related options. Is my usage of `onchange` event correct?

Initially I thought of making `aList` global, but after some reading on globals in JS, I got to know it is not a very good practice.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: `aList` contains some string values.

Comment: Provided function is anonymous function.. Have you invoked it somewhere ? Is this a handler function of some event ?

Comment: its enough to bind the event handler to a component once. You need not do it every time. The callback defined for the handler will be invoked each time the event occurs on the component.

Comment: You can change handler to `$("#cat").off().on("change", function(){
        // some computation;
    });`, this will allow you to call it many times and only have one event handler bound to your object.

Comment: @RayonDabre sorry it is not anonymous, I have updated the code snippet. Yes, the data returned by an ajax call is sent as an argument to funcName function

Comment: Yeah seems good to me, now all you need to add is `if ($(this).val() == "all") {//list all items}` and it'll be good to go.

Comment: @LukeAlderton what happens when the user selects some other option and I have to list a subset of all items?

Comment: *`I have to display everything in aList`* if you only explained what is `aList`...

Comment: add in an `else if ($(this).val() == "a") {}` after the `if(...)...`

Comment: @LukeAlderton does the display box change as and when user selects the option? I guess the page has to be reloaded! Is there any way to do it without an ajax call?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/607/?

Comment: You can append items from the array within `aList` using the jQuery `.append` function. It can take a string, so just buildup your html within it like this `$(aList).each(function() {$('#placetolist').append("<li>"+$(this)+"</li>")}` or however you decide to add the data to the screen.

Comment: @NenadVracar Thanks :)

Comment: @LukeAlderton Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
        $("#ddl").change(function () {
            var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
          var assignedRoleId = new Array();
          alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
          if(selectedValue== "all")
            {
              $("#ddl option").each(function()
                  {
                if(this.value=="all")
                  {
                    assignedRoleId.push();
                  }
                else
                  {
                    assignedRoleId.push(this.value);
                     assignedRoleId.push(" ");
                    $("#selected").html(assignedRoleId);
                    }
                 });
            }
         });
    });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select something:
<select id="ddl">
    <option value="">select one</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="all">all</option>
</select>
<div id="selected">
  </div>
```